# debug Grails app's JavaScript from IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, debugging, grails, intellij-idea, firebug

I use IntelliJ to develop Grails apps and when testing locally, I usually launch the app from IntelliJ which runs the app in an embedded Tomcat server. IntelliJ provides JavaScript debugging, but until now I've always used Firebug, but the idea of being able to use IntelliJ for all my debugging is pretty appealing.

I tried setting a breakpoint in IntelliJ and lauching the app in debug mode from inside IntelliJ, but the breakpoint was ignored. I also tried launching the app from outside IntelliJ via `grails-debug run-app`, then connecting to it with a remote JVM debugger, but the breakpoint was still ignored. Does someone know how I can debug JavaScript of a Grails app launched from IntelliJ?

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate Edition version 13

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need to do some extra work for debugging JavaScript with IntelliJ. Here are some useful articles about how you can configure your IDE and browser for JS debugging.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/intellij-idea-debugging-javascript-in-google-chrome/
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_JavaScript_with_IntelliJ_IDEA

After configuration you need to just run your Grails application in debug mode.

Comment: The first link discusses only how to debug locally in Chrome and the second tells you to select a "with JavaScript debugger" checkbox in the run configuration, but this doesn't exist (in the current IDE version) for Grails run configurations.

Comment: You are right, there are some modifications in new version, but the logic is the same. You need to select Edit Configurations from Run menu, click on '+' button to add 'JavaScript Debug', set the name, the url (for instance http://localhost:8080/appName) and select the project from the list. After run debugger and IntelliJ will suggest you to install JetBrains plugin to your browser. Install it and run your debug once again. This works for me for sure.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. In the IntelliJ JS debugger console I see a message "not connected to Firefox", maybe it's because I'm running the app over HTTPS on port 8443

Comment: did you install JetBrains plugin for firefox ?

Comment: Actually, it's working now - sort of. When I start the JS debug configuration in IntelliJ it connects to the browser and I see various CSS/JS warnings in the console pane. However, if I set a breakpoint in IntelliJ it doesn't break when that line is executed.

Comment: did you use minifying plugin in your app ? you should remove it for JS debugging.

Comment: I have the `yui-war-minify` plugin installed, but this should only minify the files when you build a WAR, not when you `run-app`

Comment: You used some plugin, which modifies static resources, try to figure out it. This way works for sure not only for me !!!